# Find Django Database in the PC

Tags: python, django, database

I am trying to create a django project and I created a simple model and ran the django server, entered the fields.  I can see all the data on the django server.  I was wondering if there is any other way to see the data entered.
[image]

This is the data I entered. Can I view it anywhere else in tabular form or database form?

This is what I do in command window:

```
sqlite3  db.sqlite3
```

followed by

```
.tables
```

Where db.sqlite3 is the file that was created when I migrated. I am not sure if the data I entered on django server is in this file.
Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

This is my models.py:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    # Site ID
    siteID = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    # End Device ID
    edevID = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

After running python
 `manage.py runserver`
I am directed to the django page where I enter the following data
[image]

And I save this. My question is how can I access this saved data in a database. I tried what you recommended Satya, it only shows me the superuser id.

I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: what kind of database do you have configured?

Comment: sqlite3. I have a file db.sqlite3 also in my oroject folder.

Comment: You can use command line tools to open up the sqlite database file. [cli docs](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)

Comment: I have tried the following:  sqlite3  db.sqlite3 followed by .tables. Dont get the data. Get some other files. Thanks

Comment: You can use something like TablePlus to view Sqlite3 in a tabluar form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install this software. After installation, select your sqlite and see your complete database.

```
DB Browser for SQLite
```

Download from here: [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can anyone explain why rather than giving the database entered straightaway, it is in one of the tables of the db.sqlite3.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't give enough information as to what you're trying to look for. I am assuming that you want more information out of the tables you've created and that you are using the default sqlite3 database. In your models.py file, you can use the special `__str__`  method to make your objects more descriptive

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.title #if your using 'title' as the attribute to identify your objects
```

Also,
enter this command in cmd

```
python manage.py shell
```

and then in the shell, import the Model whose database you want to view
for e.g.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
```

This will display all the data associated with your table. Unfortunately, not in tabular form. You can aso use the command `python manage.py inspectdb` to view all the classes associated with all tables. To view in proper tabular form, you might need [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

Comment: Yes, I am using default sqlite3 database. Also I added some more information in the question.

Comment: I saw your edit. In this case you will require an extra installation, like the one suggested by Manzurul.